# Switching carrier firmware

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, device-firmware, carriers

Can you flash different carrier firmware on the exact same model phone

For example can I take a Straight Talk Galaxy S5 and Flash u.s. Cellular Galaxy S5 firmware to it and make it work

Reason why dropped my s 5 for u.s. cellular and broke screen I was at Walmart today and seen a brand new S5 for straight talk or some other Walmart carrier and it looks nice I thought it'd be nice to have my S5 back and have a brand new one at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Different models use different baseband hardware and software tuned for the carrier's operation bands.

From what I found through search, a Straight Talk S5 (SM-S902L) is a Verizon S5 ([SM-G900V](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=5865&c=samsung_sm-g900v_galaxy_s5_lte-a__samsung_pacific)) minus the bootloader lock, which supports LTE band 4/13. This is distinctly different from a US Cellular S5 ([SM-G900R4](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=5918&c=samsung_sm-g900r4_galaxy_s5_lte-a__samsung_pacific)) with LTE band 2/4/5/12/25.

Unless you've seen explicit examples that cross-flashing a baseband worked, don't even think about it.

Comment: What I can suggest is getting a new screen of your model somewhere and replace it. Likely cheaper than a new S5.

Comment: Ya I have/trying to start a lil repair shop for Android I'm not super super smart when it come to the os as a hole but I know enughf for basic repairs and rooting and I do all the research I can when it comes to a customer I haven't made my first dollar yet but I've done a lot for one friend I think the root count is up to like 15 devices for him lol I keep telling him to look on XDA and other sites but he said I do a good job lol I bought a housing kit and some other replacement parts for my style so I'm gonna try to build it from scratch with new parts it's gonna be fun experience and I have

Comment: A back up at I found in the road with no LCD or glass that it all else fails I'll just put the screen from current at in the back up and proceed from there  untill the pixel 2 comes out then I'll be a kid in a candy store

Comment: Good to know, but do mind that the antennas (embedded in the mid-frame, I think) of different models are also often carrier-specific (once again to take care of bands), so better get one of your exact model.

Comment: Crap lol well it's for the unlocked s5 so if what I've read some where is true  it should work  I'll look in to tho

Comment: @ Andy I just had I thought I have back up s5 so I could use it if I had to but I could also just use one that's in the phone now and not use the new one if antenna problems occur

Comment: Yeah well, only when you get bad reception with the new one, you should try the old one. I don't know how well the antennas are fixed to the frame but should be able to detach them separately without keep using your frame. Anyway, good luck with the repairs!

Comment: Thanks alot I appreciate it I'll post one last comment and let you know how it went

Answer (score 0):

There are some instances where this can be done on hardware which is 'similar enough'.  I flashed the ROM for the T-Mobile Galaxy Note 2 onto my AT&T Galaxy Note 2, but **I did not flash the baseband modem bits**.

In this case the two models shared enough similarity that the image worked fine and got me what I wanted (wifi calling).  As mentioned above your mileage may vary and this can potentially brick your phone.  This is not an exercise to undertake lightly.

Comment: I really want a new one but refurbished isn't my style so I went on eBay bought a new housing  with everything glass bat cover mid frame and LCD holder (I don't know  exact name for the LCD thing ) and home button so I'll just rebuild it so it'll be almost new